# Toggle display of data returned from the database in the view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

I have two tables in my database:

```
"standard" table

+----+---------+--------------+----------------------+------------------------------------+
| id | user_id | category     | title                | content                            |
+----+---------+--------------+----------------------+------------------------------------+
| 1  |       1 | Minus        | Architecto aperiam   | Architecto aperiam odio mollitia.  | 
| 2  |       1 | Onmnis       | Est aspernatur       | Est aspernatur.                    |
| 3  |       1 | Dolor        | Delectus ratione     | Delectus ratione.                  |
| 4  |       1 | Aests        | Fugit occaecati aut  | Fugit occaecati aut.               |


"quote" table

+----+---------+------------------------------------------+------------------+
| id | user_id | content                                  | author           | 
+----+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  |       1 | Architecto aperiam odio mollitia         | Author           |
| 2  |       1 | Evitar pecados na frente dos outros      | Author           |
```

My HomeController looks like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home',
        [
        'standard' => Standard::limit(5)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get(),
        'quote' => Quote::limit(3)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get()
        ]);

    }
}
```

My "home" view looks like this:

```
@foreach($standard as $standardPost)
        <div>
            <p>{{ ($standardPost->content) }}</p>
        </div>
@endforeach

@foreach($quote as $quotePost)
        <div>
            <p>{{ ($quotePost->content) }}</p>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

In my homepage it is showing like this:

```
Last row of the "standard" table
Penultimate row of the "standard" table
Antepenultimate row of the "standard" table
 ...
Last row of "quote" table
Penultimate row of "quote" table
Antepenultimate row of "quote" table
```

But I would like the data returned from the database to be organized alternately on my homepage, as shown below:

```
Last row of the "standard" table
Last row of "quote" table

Penultimate row of the "standard" table
Penultimate row of "quote" table

Antepenultimate row of the "standard" table
Antepenultimate row of "quote" table
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not write some code to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$standard` is you longer collection, you can do something like that:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $standard->count(); $i++)
    <div>
        <p>{{ $standard->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}</p>
        <p>{{ $quote->slice($i, 1)->first()?->content }}</p>
    </div>
@endfor
```

Comment: I just tested in my view, your solution was perfect! It worked! Thanks!